# Flutter PaginatedDataTable: how to show checkbox column?

Tags: flutter, paginateddatatable

How to show the checkbox column?

```
 PaginatedDataTable(
    showCheckboxColumn: true,
    columns: _columns,
    source: _dataTableSource,
  ),
```

There is no checkbox column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document

> showCheckboxColumn → bool
> Whether the widget should display checkboxes for selectable rows.

so your DataRow must be selectable if you want to show the checkbox column,
add onSelectChanged to the DataRow

```
     DataRow(
       cells: <DataCell>[ ],
       onSelectChanged: (selected) {}
      );
```